# Service broker Activation Procedure with BULK INSERT?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert, service-broker

I have came up with the scenario where I need to process bulk insert logic within Service Broker Activation procedure. When I added bulk insert logic in Stored procedure I am getting exception.

**-Can we use "BULK INSERT" within Activation SP?? 

-Do MSSQL Service Broker Supports this????**

I googled to find ans for the above questions but found nothing. So anyone please share knowledge about this..

Thanks in advance,
sandy

Comment: Did you checked SQL Server Error Log? 
I Suppose there is user right problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Rights?

Great article can be found [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#certbulkexample). There is explained how to grant rights to execute bulk load.

Comment: Thanks for Quick replay Janis. I will Check it